# Toolbar Secondary order is not working in IOS Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

[image]Toolbar secondary order is not working in IOS Xamarin forms, I want to achieve toolbar secondary order like android in ios. My toolbar code is like this,

```
ToolbarItem tbi = new ToolbarItem()
{
    Text = "Logout",
    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary,
    Priority = 0,
};

tbi.Clicked += tbi_Clicked;
this.ToolbarItems.Add(tbi);
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Please provide an exact description with your problem instead of using `not working`.  Crash ?  not show?  behave unlike in android? Which is it.

Comment: Could you get it working?